# attempt to yield across metamethod/C-call boundary AND cannot resume non-suspended coroutine in ROBLOX STUDIO when using wait (00.1)

Tags: lua, roblox

This is my code

```
-- Script by supermarioclub231 as known as marioroblox102, and special thanks to jacko for some scripts things

-- idk
-- Player
local plr = game.Players:CreateLocalPlayer(0)
game:GetService("Visit")
game:GetService("RunService"):run()
plr:LoadCharacter()

-- have to do this so that the same numbers arent generated every time

math.random(); math.random(); math.random()

digits = 4 -- the amount of times to add digits to the end of the player name

prefix = "NoName "
suffix = "" -- wouldnt wanna type anything here, the digits will be added here!

for i=1, digits do
    suffix = suffix .. math.random(1,9)
    i = i + 1;
end

plr.Name = prefix .. suffix

-- shopium brings to you...

shirt = Instance.new("Shirt", plr)
pants = Instance.new("Pants", plr)
shirt.ShirtTemplate = "rbxasset://shirts/jared.png"
pants.PantsTemplate = "rbxasset://pants/jeans.png"

while true do
    wait (0.001)
    if plr.Character.Humanoid.Health <= 0 then
        wait(5)
        plr:LoadCharacter(true)
    elseif plr.Character.Parent  == nil then 
      wait(5) 
      plr:LoadCharacter(true) 
    end
end
```

everytime i run it, i get this

[image: 1]

the line 39 is wait(000.1),
why its not working?
its supossed to do something forever
like a loop
but it gives me a error

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't have to you use math.random() three times at the start so it doesn't generate the same script everytime as thats not how it works it will generate a random number between the range you specify every time and the number may be the same every once in a while but thats why its called math.random() but I'm also working on fixing the rest of you script just wanted to tell you that. Also just use the ROBLOX Health Changed Event and the link to the wiki of that event is [here](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Humanoid/HealthChanged).